# please help with my arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

My problem is when I run code like this:

```
char directioN;

void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(9600)   
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    directioN = Serial.read();

    switch (directioN)
    {
      case 'F':
        break;

      case 'B':
        break;

      case 'R':
        break;

      case 'L':
        break;

      default :
        break;
    }

    Serial.print("direction is:");
    Serial.println(directioN);
  }
}
```

My serial monitor add another input, but the second one is empty; this happened here with char both as with int.

But when i tried the same code in tinkercad it worked fine.

So do I really need a new ATMEGA328 or it can be done by software or something?

**I use an Arduino Uno

Comment: what have you set in Serial Monitor as line ending to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why you don't just ignore it?

```
if(directionN >= 32){   //check if char is readable ascii character
  Serial.print("direction is:");
  Serial.println(directioN);
}
```

Comment: How i ignore. it affect how my code run cause a specific input do a specific function so the following zero or null input which im talking about here cause the wanted function to end

Comment: @nouralbrmky Like in the code i posted, null input is probably newline.

Comment: It worked fine thank you .do u have any idea what may cause some thing like that to happen and i 'll be more thankful

Comment: @nouralbrmky It's probably caused by newline character which is sent after text. Newline decimal value in ascii table is smaller than 32 and that's why this code ignores it.